# Docker: How to increase the size of tmpfs volumes?

Tags: docker

I observed that the size of the `tmpfs` volumes created by `docker` is roughly half the size of the machine's physical memory.

For example, on a machine with 22GB of RAM, I got this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay         970G  130G  840G  14% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs            12G     0   12G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            20G     0   20G   0% /ramdisk
/dev/sda1       970G  130G  840G  14% /etc/hosts
tmpfs            12G  180K   12G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            12G     0   12G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs            12G     0   12G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs            12G     0   12G   0% /sys/firmware
```

I would like to increase this size. Could anybody please tell me how to do that?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

**Update:** Let me add some context to this question.

In my docker I have a `/ramdisk` volume whose size is large (here 20GB) because one of my programs needs that:

```
nvidia-docker run --ipc=host -h $HOSTNAME --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/ramdisk,tmpfs-mode=1770,tmpfs-size=21474836480
```

When running the program, at the moment its memory usage surpasses 12GB of `ramdisk`, it crashes (while `ramdisk` still has 8GB left). Note that 12GB is the size of the other `tmpfs` system volumes.

So, one solution I could think of is to increase the size of those other volumes, which is my question.

Comment: Have a look at `dmesg`. I suspect the crash might be caused by: 1. Insufficient amount of free RAM. 2. Issues with the software in the container itself (check logs), 3. Limitation of container os like Alpine linux (issues with libc/glibc implementation. If you see OOM the problem is with other software eating up the RAM.

Comment: @Szczad Thanks. 1 is unlikely because I was monitoring free RAM as well than obsrved that the process did not eat up RAM (used amount stayed constant), only `ramdisk` was increasing. I'll make a video to clearly show the behaviour of all these components. (Unfortunately I'm not able to do it right now but in 20 hours or so). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As per docker docs (20GiB as per example):

```
docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name tmptest \
  --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/app,tmpfs-mode=1770,tmpfs-size=21474836480 \
  nginx:latest
```

PS: Docs specify that by default tmpfs volumes have unlimited size, so the calculations here might be rounded down to the amount of free memory in the host OS.

SRC: https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/#specify-tmpfs-options

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that your command will change the size of `/app` only and not the default `tmpfs` ones (i.e. `/sys/fs/cgroup, /dev/shm,/proc/acpi,/proc/scsi,/sys/firmware`) :(

Comment: These are inherited from host OS and in fact - are pseudo FS'es not to be used by ordinary user (apart from /dev/shm). If you wish to use TMPFS yourself please create one explicitly. `/sys` is pseudo FS used to access device information, `/proc` to get insight the processes. The only exception here is `/dev/shm` which is in fact shared memory segment for IPC.

Comment: Actually I explicitly created one: `/ramdisk`, but there was an issue with that. Please see the update in my question. Thanks again.